# Testing integrity of Javascript AES encrpytion

Tags: javascript, aes

Are the implementation of these two AES 256 scripts the same?

The first one appears to be a minified/compressed version of the gibberish, but I cannot tell what the variables are.

compressed version:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/a3diti/aes256-offline/master/data/gibberish-aes-1.0.0.min.js

original:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdp/gibberish-aes/master/dist/gibberish-aes-1.0.0.js

How can I test the integrity of these scripts. They do encrypt but how do I know that the key is sufficiently random.

I used the first one because it is shorter and it seems to work ,but not sure.

Comment: They should be the same. Minification is a simple, automated process that should produce equivalent code.

Comment: The repositories from which these scripts are taken should include the original (non-minified) source code as well as the build steps to arrive at the minified version. Run them for yourself and try to reproduce the output if you don't trust the supplier and/or suspect the author has included bugs only in the distributed version.

Comment: If you go to the main Github page it says this library is deprecated. They recommend using other libraries instead.